# WiringPi vs default Raspbian RPi.GPIO module

Tags: arduino, python

Can anyone explain the difference between WiringPi and the default RPi.GPIO module that comes with raspbian?

What extra features does WiringPi have?

Answer (score 3):

wiringPi is a C library.  Bindings have been provided for other languages like Python and Java.  As mentioned above wiringPi comes with a command line utility called gpio which is setuid root so the gpio utility can be run by a non-root user.

RPi.GPIO is a Python module.

Programs linked against wiringPi have to be run as root as does any Python program which imports RPi.GPIO.

If you look at the web-sites you can make a feature comparison.  Generally wiringPi has a lot more features available, SPI/I2C, Gert board ec.

Answer (score 2):

WiringPi has a command line utility called 'gpio'.  This makes it possible to control GPIO pins from the command line.  Read about it here: http://wiringpi.com/the-gpio-utility/

WiringPi doesn't need to be run as root, but programs built with the RPi.GPIO module do need to be run as root.